# runtime error 1004. method range of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a

> run-time error '1004': method 'range'of object'_worksheet'failed

I'm assuming it is the line where it is

```
Set datarng = purchfcst.Range("A2:Q" & datalastrow)
```

I'm unsure as what the error as I can't see an error with this

```
Sub updatepacksizecostandorders()

Dim cofws As Worksheet, purchfcst As Worksheet
Dim coflastrow As Long, purchlastrow As Long
Dim datarng As Range


Set cofws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COF Replen")
Set purchfcst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("purchase forecast")

coflastrow = cofws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
purchlastrow = purchfcst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set datarng = purchfcst.Range("A2:Q" & datalastrow)

For x = 2 To coflastrow
    On Error Resume Next
    cofws.Range("G" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cofws.Range("A" & x).Value.datarng, 2, False)


Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, `Rows.Count` should be a qualified reference: `purchfcst.Rows.Count` or it just refers to the active worksheet instead of the one you are assuming it refers to.

Comment: Then make sure `datalastrow` does not equal zero, and remove the `On Error Resume Next` and set a break point at the first line, and step thru it line by line, checking the values of your variables as you go.

Comment: You have a period where there should be a comma `VLookup(cofws.Range("A" & x).Value, datarng, 2, False)`

Comment: how do i check the datalastrow does not equal zero?

Comment: hi tim, even with the comma i still get the same error

Comment: You did not declared the value of 'datalastrow' anywhere, that is the main problem.

Comment: sorry i'm new to vba, how would i declare the value of the datalastrow?

Comment: You need to assign it a value as you have done for `purchlastrow` etc.